# what is a good practice to change the default timeout globally or for one test only? mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-2016

I am using `before` hook with `try catch` block for calling some functionality inside my try block. So `before` block runs before each `it`.

```
describe('Function response', ()=> {
  // this.timeout(5000); //here
  let response;
  before(async () => {
   // this.timeout(500000); //or here
    try {
      response = await myFunction(argument);
    } catch (err) {
      assert.fail(err);//seems doesn't work
    }
  });
  it('function response to be an array', () => {
    expect(response).to.be.an('array');
  });
});
```

I am getting this error

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

After opening one of the comments that change default timeout after of course making arrow functions to regular, the test works as expected. 
**I would like to know what is the best practice. Maybe it's better to change the default timeout in `test` script?**

`"test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts --timeout 5000`

Also maybe I am not handling the error in `catch` block correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to set the timeout at the needed scope:

```
describe('something', function() {
  this.timeout(100);  // sets the timeout for everything in "describe"

  before(function(done) {
    this.timeout(500);  // sets the timeout ONLY for "before"
    setTimeout(done, 450);  // <= this works
  });

  it('should do something', function (done) {
    setTimeout(done, 150);  //  <= this times out
  });
});
```

- If you need a particular timeout for **all** your tests, then set it at the global level
- If you need a particular timeout for **everything** within a `describe`, set it in the `describe`
- If you need a particular timeout for **one** `before`, `it`, etc., set it in that function

Comment: ...and your `catch` won't catch a `timeout` error because that is thrown by `mocha` and not your test code.

Comment: what about arrow functions? I would't like to rewrite those to regular functions

Comment: And what if in another server the timeout won't be needed?

Comment: ["Passing arrow functions (aka "lambdas") to Mocha is discouraged."](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions) - best practice with `mocha` is to use normal functions

Comment: "And what if in another server the timeout won't be needed?"  <= I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: I am waiting for some response from server which I am keeping into `response` variable. What if in another 'local machine' the internet connection is faster hence the response is coming faster let's assume before the timeout exceeds. In that machine I wouldn't be needed timeout right?

Comment: Just set your timeout to the longest time needed.  If the response comes back faster that's not a problem.

Comment: (also just a quick note: while it *can* be necessary to make network requests during unit tests, in general it is best to avoid it.  Server code is typically tested directly within the server unit tests, and client code typically mocks server responses in its unit tests)